# Destroying resources from outside the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

Is it un-RESTful/un-Ruby/bad practice to destroy objects in ruby on rails by doing a ".destroy" on an active record outside it's controller? For instance, when a user is destroyed I call destroy on all their posts from the User controller.

Comment: In this case (posts belonging to a user), you should use the option `has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy` in the User's class. It will automatically call `.destroy` on each Post returned by `user.posts`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ActiveRecord**

In reference to `jkeuhlen`'s answer, I would not say it's outright bad practice to destroy an ActiveRecord object from a different controller, in principle.

In your case, it would not be very efficient to do it your way, but it wouldn't be against convention in my opinion:

[image]

As I understand, the MVC programming pattern basically means that if you call a `controller`, its primary function is to build a set of data depending on the users' input. This may, or may not, involve the controller's corresponding model

Although against the Resourceful principle directly, I don't see why it would be a problem to destroy data depending on various controller actions - if it doesn't involve the model, surely you'd be able to destroy all the relevant data from that controller?

--

**Rails**

As pointed out by `jkeuhlen`, Rails comes with a [`dependent: :destroy`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) method to remove associative data upon record deletion.

The only thing to add to `jkheuhlen`'s answer is as follows (taken from the answer):

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
end
```

[image]

This would mean that if you called the following, you need to make sure you're able to call the following:

```
#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
Class UsersController < ApplicationController
   def destroy
       @user = User.find params[:id]
       @user.destroy -> will destroy all associated `posts`
   end
end
```

Comment: What does the as: :attachable do? That looks to me like you are setting up a polymorphic association?

Comment: Yes, but it shouldn't matter in regards to what you're trying to set up

Comment: So what does the second Post model you posted add to my answer/do differently? I just feel like I'm missing something here, not trying to attack your answer or anything.

Comment: It doesn't do anything differently sorry - I took it from the Rails documentation - I should have labelled it better :)

Comment: Ah okay thanks for the clarification there I was staring at it for awhile trying to figure out how they were really different at all.

Comment: Lol no - I wanted to reinforce your answer whilst providing an example from the Rails documentation itself!

Answer (score 2):

I would say yes, it is bad practice to do this. But mostly because there is a better way that rails has implemented for you. Like MrYoshiji pointed out in his comment, you should create an association between the user and a post.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Then when you delete a user, rails will automagically handle the destroys of the posts.

Comment: Well the problem with doing that, and I didn't want to get into this too much in the question, is that I have an "Organization" resource that can have other sub-organizations, but this is only enforced in the database, not in rails magic. As far as I know there is no way to easily enforce dependencies within a given resource, so when I delete an organization I manually go through and get rid of all the subs. It sounds like this is not too blasphemous from the answers posted here, so I think I will continue to do it unless someone can suggest a good alternative. Thank you for the input.